# Get specific item from Core Data as JSON

Tags: json, swift

I have a Core Data entity Checkout that has just one attribute which is transformable and set as [String:Any]:

```
cart : [String:Any]
```

Now I use this function to retrieve the items in the cart:

```
 func getCheckOutItems()->  [NSDictionary]{
    let request : NSFetchRequest<Checkout> = Checkout.fetchRequest()
    request.propertiesToFetch = ["cart"]
    request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    var checkout : [NSDictionary]!
    var cart : [String:Any]!
    do{
        checkout = try context.fetch(request)
    }catch{
        print ("Error fetching data")
    }
    return checkout
}
```

Now i need to add these items to a dictionary which also contains other items like this:

```
 var cart = [String:Any]()
    cart["cart"] = getCheckOutItems()
    cart["telco"] = "something"
    cart["fcm_token"] = "tokden"
    cart["email"] = "email"
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: cart, options: [])
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
    print("Printing JSON \(jsonString)")
```

This is in order to produce a json result like this:

```
{
"fcm_token": "tokden",
"cart": [{
        "entity": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "id": 428,
        "price": 80,
        "date": "30 Jan 2018",
        "seat_no": 20,
        "type": "bus",
        "item": "STANDARD",
        "schedule_id": 132
    },
    {
        "entity": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "id": 1539,
        "price": 110,
        "date": "30 Jan 2018",
        "seat_no": 7,
        "type": "bus",
        "item": "EXECUTIVE",
        "schedule_id": 131
    },
    {
        "entity": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "id": 282,
        "price": 40,
        "date": "30 Jan 2018",
        "seat_no": 1,
        "type": "bus",
        "item": "STANDARD",
        "schedule_id": 114
    }
],
"telco": "something",
"email": "email"
```

}

The main aim is to ensure that when the cart items are attached to the final json result, they are attached as an array with key "cart". However, since I am unable to loop through to get each item cart, when I add this to the JSON, I get the result like so:

```
{
"fcm_token": "tokden",
"cart": [{
    **"cart": {**
        "entity": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "id": 428,
        "price": 80,
        "date": "30 Jan 2018",
        "seat_no": 20,
        "type": "bus",
        "item": "STANDARD",
        "schedule_id": 132
    }
}, {
    "cart": {
        "entity": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "id": 1539,
        "price": 110,
        "date": "30 Jan 2018",
        "seat_no": 7,
        "type": "bus",
        "item": "EXECUTIVE",
        "schedule_id": 131
    }
}, {
    "cart": {
        "entity": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "id": 282,
        "price": 40,
        "date": "30 Jan 2018",
        "seat_no": 1,
        "type": "bus",
        "item": "STANDARD",
        "schedule_id": 114
    }
}],
"telco": "something",
"email": "email"
```

}

How can I format this result such that the "cart" key is eliminated to format the json as indicated earlier

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library to saving json to coredata and vice versa.

[Click this link for the library 3Lvis Library](https://github.com/3lvis/Sync)